# Jetty9 Basic Auth for specific directories

Tags: java, jetty, basic-authentication, jetty-9

We are running multiple Java webapps which use Jetty9 as server.

The apps are reachable via subdirectories:

- domain.tld/app1
- domain.tld/app2
- domain.tld/app3

Now I want to protect two of those apps via basic auth.

When using Apache as server this would be quite easy to achieve via .htaccess or the vhost conf file, but how can I achieve this with Jetty?

Unfortunately the Jetty docs didn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now I got the following in my jetty-context.xml, but nothing happens:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
        <Set name="contextPath">/app1</Set>
        <Set name="war">/opt/software/web/view.war</Set>
        <Set name="handler">
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler" id="RequestLog">
                        <Set name="requestLog">
                                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog" id="RequestLogImpl">
                                        <Set name="filename">/home/software/something/log/access-something-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Set>
                                        <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyy_MM_dd</Set>
                                        <Set name="logTimeZone">GMT</Set>
                                        <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
                                        <Set name="append">true</Set>
                                        <Set name="logLatency">true</Set>
                                </New>
                        </Set>
                </New>
        </Set>

  <Get name="securityHandler">
    <Set name="loginService">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
            <Set name="name">Software</Set>
            <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/software/realm.properties</Set>
            <Call name="start"></Call>
      </New>
    </Set>
  </Get>

</Configure>
```

Content of realm.properties:

```
admin: password,admin,user
```

Comment: What version of Jetty are you using? The current version documentation has instructions for scoping auth: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-authentication.html#_scoping_security_realms

The TL;DR being that you need to first define a security realm and then configure your contexts to use it, such as in the context xml file.

Comment: are these formal Servlet WebApps or something custom?

Comment: @Walkerwatch I will try it and let you know whether it worked or not.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Honestly I don't know. How can I find out?

Comment: @Walkerwatch I updated my question with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up something to trigger the authentication. Based on what you've provided, BASIC auth should suit your needs. You've already declared the `HashLoginService` in your context XML file, but you also need to declare the auth type in the WEB-INF/web.xml of the webapp itself. This would look something like:

```xml
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>My Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

You also need to define the security/auth constraints of the auth method in the web.xml. This helps determine who is allowed access to what, based on role, URL..etc. An example of restricting the webapp entirely might look like:

```xml
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <role-name>other</role-name>
    <role-name>roles</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Jetty supports other [Authentication mechanisms](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-authentication.html#_configuring_an_authentication_mechanism) as well if something better suits your needs.

So to recap, to scope your security *per webapp* you need to do a few things:

1. Declare the type of authentication for the webapp in the WEB-INF/web.xml
2. Define the security/auth constraints for the webapp in the WEB-INF/web.xml
3. Define the type of the LoginService (Hash in this case) in the context XML file for the webapp, and provide the path to the associated properties file.